# Ruby: Compilation error during installation of ‘rails’ gem on macOS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, rubygems

When I install rails in macOS by running

```sh
$ sudo gem install rails
```

I got the following.

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150702-37637-10z8fhh.rb extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
checking if the C compiler accepts -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future... no
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
checking for gzdopen() in -lz... yes
checking for iconv... yes
************************************************************************
IMPORTANT NOTICE:

Building Nokogiri with a packaged version of libxml2-2.9.2
with the following patches applied:
    - 0001-Revert-Missing-initialization-for-the-catalog-module.patch
    - 0002-Fix-missing-entities-after-CVE-2014-3660-fix.patch

Team Nokogiri will keep on doing their best to provide security
updates in a timely manner, but if this is a concern for you and want
to use the system library instead; abort this installation process and
reinstall nokogiri as follows:

    gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
        [--with-xml2-config=/path/to/xml2-config]
        [--with-xslt-config=/path/to/xslt-config]

If you are using Bundler, tell it to use the option:

    bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
    bundle install

Note, however, that nokogiri is not fully compatible with arbitrary
versions of libxml2 provided by OS/package vendors.
************************************************************************
Extracting libxml2-2.9.2.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin14/ports/libxml2/2.9.2... OK
Running patch with /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxml2/0001-Revert-Missing-initialization-for-the-catalog-module.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxml2 2.9.2... OK
Running patch with /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxml2/0002-Fix-missing-entities-after-CVE-2014-3660-fix.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxml2 2.9.2... OK
Running 'configure' for libxml2 2.9.2... OK
Running 'compile' for libxml2 2.9.2... ERROR, review '/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ext/nokogiri/tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin14/ports/libxml2/2.9.2/compile.log' to see what happened.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
    --help
    --clean
    --use-system-libraries
    --enable-static
    --disable-static
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --enable-cross-build
    --disable-cross-build
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mini_portile-0.6.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:279:in `block in execute': Failed to complete compile task (RuntimeError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mini_portile-0.6.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:271:in `chdir'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mini_portile-0.6.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:271:in `execute'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mini_portile-0.6.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:70:in `compile'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mini_portile-0.6.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:110:in `cook'
    from extconf.rb:278:in `block in process_recipe'
    from extconf.rb:177:in `tap'
    from extconf.rb:177:in `process_recipe'
    from extconf.rb:475:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-14/2.0.0/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building gems with native extensions is always a pain. You need to have several libs or compile tools installed. In case of nokogiri it's libxml. For this reason i would recommend to use [rvm](https://rvm.io/) for getting started. RVM is not the cleanest tool, when it comes to unix philosophy, but it's a full-stack solution, meaning that it just works out of the box. It will install all the dependencies for you, using the default osx package manager. As a package manager i recommend [homebrew](http://brew.sh/).

```sh
#install homebrew
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

#install rvm into $HOME
brew install gpg
gpg --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable

rvm install ruby --latest

gem install rails #no sudo, as ruby is in $HOME
```

Comment: I found that if I do not add sudo before gem, I will have this error
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.

Comment: because you are using Mac OSX system ruby. If you would install a ruby version by rvm, as i described in the answer,  it will go in your home directory and will not require root permissions. (given you install rvm in home, too)

Comment: I think gpg is successfully installed.
gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 1.4.18

but not rvm, I did 
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
$ \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
but then I run 
rvm --version
zsh: command not found: rvm

Comment: It works now. I just solved some minor issues. Thanks!

Comment: I did install ruby with rvm, but I'm getting this same error

Comment: check `rvm requirements`. It will install all missing dependencies for rvm via your packagemanger (hombrew, macports)